# Scrapy submit form repeatly

Tags: python, scrapy

It can work with only one username plus password and verification code.

Here is the logic:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield request(indexUrl, headers=headers, callback=self.downloadPic)

def downloadPic(self, response):
    # get cookies from the response and add it to the headers
    yield request(picUrl, headers=headers, callback=self.handlePic)

def handlePic(self, response):
    # extract text from the picture
    # form data include username, password and verification code
    yield FormRequest(postUrl, formdata, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)
```

Let's say we have a lot of username and password in the local. And I want to repeat this logoc many times, just change the username and password in the formdata.

I have tried to use for loop to get every username and password, then yield a new request, but it doesn't work.

So any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I write a script to call my spider, pass the form data to it. and it works!